# How to find function $F$ such that $F''(x)=\cos{x^2}$, $F'(0)=3$ and $F(0)=4$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series, taylor-expansion

Here we want $F\in \Bbb{R}$. We use Taylor Series.

I get $F''(x)=\cos{x^2}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}(x^2)^{2k}=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}x^{4k}$

Integrating, we have $F'(x)=C+\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!(4k+1)}x^{4k+1}$. Since the first term is with $x$ and $F'(0)=3$, so $C=3$

Integrating a again, $F(x)=C+3x+\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!(4k+1)(4k+2)}x^{4k+2}$. So $C=4$ this time.

Therefore $F(x)=4+3x+\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!(4k+1)(4k+2)}x^{4k+2}$

However I doubt that my procedure follows correctly. Could someone tell?

Comment: Taylor expansion of $\cos(x)$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k}$, not as written. Besides this little mistake, to me it seems like you are on the right track.